# Typeorm Many to Many Custom Table with camelCase Column Names

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

i have these entities that has many to many relation. I use custom table because of additional columns. And use camelCase column names. But in relation definitions, although I tried both snake case and camel case column names, I get an error either in adding or listing.

Here are my entities:

```
const Product = {
...

    categories: {
      type: 'many-to-many',
      target: Category
      joinTable: {
        name: category_product
        joinColumn: {
          name: 'product_id',
          referencedColumnName: 'id',
        },
        inverseJoinColumn: {
          name: 'category_id',
          referencedColumnName: 'id',
        },
      },
      inverseSide: 'products',
      cascade: true,
    },
}
```

```
const Category = {
...

   products: {
      type: 'many-to-many',
      target: Product
      joinTable: {
        name: category_product
        joinColumn: {
          name: 'categoryId',
          referencedColumnName: 'id',
        },
        inverseJoinColumn: {
          name: 'productId',
          referencedColumnName: 'id',
        },
      }, 
}
```

```
const CategoryProduct = {
  name: 'category_product'
  columns: {    
    id: {
      name: 'id'
      primary: true,
      type: 'int8',
      generated: true,
    },
    categoryId: {
      name: 'category_id'
      type: 'uuid',
    },
    productId: {
      name: 'product_id'
      type: 'uuid',
    },
  },
  relations: {
    category: {
      type: 'many-to-one',
      target: 'Category'
      joinColumn: {
        name: category_id',
        
      },
      onDelete: 'cascade',
      onUpdate: 'cascade',
      
    },
    product: {
      type: 'many-to-one',
      target: 'Product'
      joinColumn: {
        name: 'product_id',
        
      },
      onDelete: 'cascade',
      onUpdate: 'cascade',
      
    },
  },
}
```

My typeorm version: 0.3.10

I try camel-snake case combinations with columns and chaning inverSide fields. But either i get 'column not exists' or 'null value in column' error when i change snake-camel

Answer (score -1):

```js
// Product entity
@Entity()
class Product {
  // Other columns and properties

  @ManyToMany(() => Category, (category) => category.products)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'category_product',
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'product_id',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'category_id',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
  })
  categories: Category[];
}

// Category entity
@Entity()
class Category {
  // Other columns and properties

  @ManyToMany(() => Product, (product) => product.categories)
  products: Product[];
}
```

```js
// CategoryProduct entity (Custom Join Table)
@Entity('category_product')
class CategoryProduct {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Category, (category) => category.products, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'category_id' })
  category: Category;

  @ManyToOne(() => Product, (product) => product.categories, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'product_id' })
  product: Product;
}
```

Comment: Hello, Is this typescript version of my entities? What part should i change or remove? I use javascript.